# Using a MediaPlayer in an AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-appwidget

I have a simple widget that plays a sound file when pressed. Right now, I have this code in the onRecieve method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    int id = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(CreateWidget.PREFS, 0);
    Log.d("WORKING",SFXAppWidgetProvider.KEY_SFX_URI_PREFIX+id+" = "+prefs.getString(SFXAppWidgetProvider.KEY_SFX_URI_PREFIX+id, "FAILURE"));
    Log.d("WORKING", "Received Intent: " + intent.getAction());

    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY_SOUND))
    {
        try
        {
            if(mPlayer != null)
            {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
                Uri sfxURI= Uri.parse(prefs.getString(SFXAppWidgetProvider.KEY_SFX_URI_PREFIX+id, "null"));
                mPlayer.setDataSource(context, sfxURI);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();
                Log.d("WORKING","MediaPlayer already existed, released it");
            }
            else
            {
                Uri sfxURI= Uri.parse(prefs.getString(SFXAppWidgetProvider.KEY_SFX_URI_PREFIX+id, "null"));
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, sfxURI);
                mPlayer.start();
                Log.d("WORKING","MediaPlayer did not exist, making a new one");
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

What happens is that the log keeps reporting that it's creating a new MediaPlayer instance every time I play the sound. I'm guessing that AppWidgetRecievers/BroadcastReceivers aren't meant to have objects or something? Anyone know an alternate way to play sounds (preferrably lightweight, since it's only a widget. And I guess it may be more efficient to use a SoundPool since it's possible to have multiple different sounds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing that AppWidgetRecievers/BroadcastReceivers aren't meant to have objects or something?

Manifest-registered `BrodadcastReceivers`, like an `AppWidgetProvider`, live only as long as the `onReceive()` call does. It is not safe for them to do anything that lives much past the end of `onReceive()`, and they are not reused.

> Anyone know an alternate way to play sounds (preferrably lightweight, since it's only a widget.

If your goal is to play sound for an extended period, have the `AppWidgetProvider` delegate the work to a `Service` that manages the audio playback.

> And I guess it may be more efficient to use a SoundPool since it's possible to have multiple different sounds)?

There may be scenarios in which `SoundPool` is a better option than `MediaPlayer`, but it is unlikely that any of those scenarios have anything to do with app widgets.

Comment: So it would be better to have one sound loaded at a time using a MediaPlayer, than having all the sounds loaded in a SoundPool?

Comment: Also, how would I tell the service to play a sound while it's running?

Comment: @RahatAhmed: "how would I tell the service to play a sound while it's running?" -- package data in the `Intent` you use with `startService()` to identify what the service should play back.